# Linq to SQL gives NotSupportedException when using local variables

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

It appears to me that it matters whether you use a variable to temporary store an IQueryable or not. See the simplified example below:

This works:

```
List<string> jobNames = new List<string> { "ICT" };
var ictPeops = from p in dataContext.Persons
               where (  from j in dataContext.Jobs
                        where jobNames.Contains(j.Name)
                        select j.ID).Contains(p.JobID)
               select p;
```

But when I use a variable to temporary store the subquery I get an exception:

```
List<string> jobNames = new List<string> { "ICT" };
var jobs = from j in dataContext.Jobs
           where jobNames.Contains(j.Name)
           select j.ID;
var ictPeops = from p in dataContext.Persons
               where jobs.Contains(p.JobID)
               select p;
```

> "System.NotSupportedException: Queries
>   with local collections are not
>   supported"

I don't see what the problem is. Isn't this logic that is supposed to work in LINQ?

UPDATE:
Yesterday I found the workaround to get 1 query while using multiple variables:

```
  var jobs = from j in dataContext.Jobs
             where jobNames.Contains(j.Name)
             select j.ID;
  var ictPeops = from p in dataContext.Persons
                 join j in jobs on p.JobID equals j
                 select p;
```

But still I'm confused. Can anyone shed some light on why the first query didn't work when using a variable?

Comment: i was not able to reproduce that. please upload yout Linq to SQL schema and send us link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ-2-SQL translates your code into T-SQL. It is able to pass your List of job names over as a parameter easily. But, in your failing query you are trying to join a SQL table (Persons) to a C# object (jobs); this is a complex C# type which cannot be translated into SQL. You probably need to convert jobs into a simple int array before using it in the second query. LINQ-2-SQL might be able to handle that.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. The "complex" c# type your referring to is an IQueryable<int> which source is the same datacontext. When I convert it into an IEnumerable (like an array) it then it works, but linq2sql will execute 2 queries. That is not an option.

Comment: I think the exception that was generated described the problem quite succinctly: "Queries with local collections are not supported". It is a limitation of LINQ-2-SQL.

Comment: If jobNames is a simple data structure (i.e. List, Array) then the code "where jobNames.Contains(j.Name)" results in SQL that looks like "WHERE Name IN (@p0, @p1, ...)". But since since jobNames is an IQueryable, L2S cannot translate this. Your third example works because the syntax is different: "join j in jobs on p.JobID equals j". L2S stills knows at this point that 'j' refers to the Jobs table so the resulting SQL would look something like: "FROM [Persons] AS [t0] INNER JOIN [Jobs] AS [t1] ON [t0].[JobID] = [t1].[ID]"

Answer (score 0):

try converting var `jobs`  to Type of `IList`

```
var jobs = (from j in dataContext.Jobs
            where jobNames.Contains(j.Name)
            select j.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: Nope, this is not what I'm looking for. Of course ToList is gonna work, but than 2 queries are generated. In my business that would mean the second select query would have about 30000 intput parameters and that should not be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, does this work?  (I'm not a big LINQ-to-SQL dude)

```
var jobNames = from s in new string[] { "ICT" } 
        select s; 
var jobs = from j in dataContext.Jobs 
       where jobNames.Contains(j.Name) 
       select j.ID; 
var ictPeops = from p in dataContext.Persons 
           where jobs.Contains(p.JobID) 
           select p;
```

EDIT: Ok, how about one big query? :)

```
var ictPeops = 
    from p in dataContext.Persons
        let jobs =
           from j in dataContext.Jobs
           let jobNames = from s in new string[]{"ICT"} select s
           where jobNames.Contains(j.Name)
           select j.ID
    where jobs.Contains(p.JobID)
    select p;
```

Comment: Nope, same problem. The first part will work, because jobNames is of type IEnumerable<string> and is treated the same as the list of strings I used. 

Same problem with the selection if ictPeops though....

Comment: Nope, with your second query I get the same famous System.NotSupportedException. Note that my very first query does work.

Comment: Oh, I saw - I was just curious about the "is supported" overlap between LINQ-to-SQL and "normal" LINQ.

Answer (score -1):

Let me explain how Linq to SQL works. When you write query in the code, this code is not executed as other .net code and Linq to Objects. This code then is broken down into expression tree and compiled to SQL. If you write everything as single expression it is converted to SQL entirely. When you break to two queries it will be broken into two separate queries. And Linq To SQL can't assemble them.

Comment: This is not correct. Because the two queries are both expression trees, LINQ to SQL will produce one SQL statement. That is not the problem here.

Comment: "LINQ to SQL will produce one SQL statement" - can you prove that?

Comment: See my update, given linq query generates following query: 
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[JobID]
FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Job] AS [t1] ON [t0].[JobID] = [t1].[ID]
WHERE [t1].[Name] IN (@p0)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [ICT]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1